# Dirac measure m in the form of $m=\alpha \lambda$, for some constant $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'd like to prove the following statement:

> $m$ is a Dirac measure iff for every other measure $\lambda$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$ satisfies $\lambda=\alpha m$ for some constant $\alpha$.

Note "$\lambda$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$" means $m(E)=0 \implies \lambda(E)=0$ for some measurable set $E$. I found one direction of the proof relatively easy:

Suppose $m_x$ is Dirac measure: it has measure zero for measurable set $A$ that doesn't contain element $\{x\}$ and measure 1 for set $A$ containing $\{x\}$. Let $E$ be an arbitrary measurable set, suppose $x \not \in E$, we have $m(E -\{x\})=0 \implies \lambda(E -\{x\})=0$. Hence we have $\lambda(E)=\lambda(E -\{x\})+\lambda(\{x\})=\lambda(\{x\})$. Put $\alpha=\lambda(\{x\})$ would finish this part of the proof.

Any idea for the other direction of the proof?

Comment: Technically this statement might not be true depending on how restrictive your notion of "Dirac measure" is. For example, is $m$ defined on $P(\{ 1,2 \})$ with $m(\{ 1,2 \})=1$ and $m(A)=0$ for the other three subsets of $\{ 1,2 \}$ a "Dirac measure" in your sense?

Comment: that would not be $\sigma$ additive

Comment: Sorry, in my example $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 2 \}$ both needed to not be measurable.